# Can a single USB device emulate multiple USB devices?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-hub

I'm interested in the idea that my USB device can carry its own drivers.  I'd like the device the be plugged in, enumerated, and if a driver does not attach to it within a few seconds and initialize it, it also connects as a USB drive, and provides drivers on that drive.  Once the driver contacts the device, then the drive would be disconnected.

Do I have to design my device to be a USB hub, with two USB devices that attach and detach from that virtual hub, or does the USB specification have a way to allow this sort of design without pretending to be a hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are such devices. For example the E3131 Huawei UMTS modem works that way. It does not implement a hub, but it is an *USB composite device*.
In Linux, the *usb-devices* command returns its descriptors as:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1506 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=16 Driver=cdc_ncm
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=03 Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=02 Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

It offers two usb-storage devices. The first one emulates the CD-ROM with drivers, the second is the SD memory card.

I don't know, what tools are you using to create the firmware.
If you are using [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php), you can find some examples in the sources
(e.g. Mass Storage/Keyboard Device , Virtual Serial/Mass Storage Device).